# PowerBI gives different results than MySQL. Can someone help me?

Tags: mysql, powerbi

When I use COUNT in MySQL, for example, Mrs. Aretha Salas gets 18 movies, but in powerBI, using COUNT says 20 movies. 18 movies is the correct value. How do I get this resolved?

In MySQL

[image: In MySQL]

In PBI

[image: In PowerBI]

In PBI

[image: PowerBI]

Comment: Its really hard to follow based on screen prints.  To get an improved response, try and frame your question with a data example (rather than screen prints), based on the minimum amount of data needed to demonstrate the issue.  The aim is to provide a way to recreate quickly for anyone answering

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Power BI to be coming up with a different figure, there will be a join to another table or a second row (possibly duplicate) in your film table increasing the count.

Brake the table into a separate Power BI workbook and perform the same test.  If you are still getting the same result in your new workbook, turn the visual into a table and that should explain how the count is coming out incorrect.